# SQL Server PK problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is a screenshot of my db when I execute this query

```
INSERT INTO Products(CategoryID, TypeID, BarCode, ArtNumber, ProductName, Price, SelfPrice, PriceWithOutAWD, UnitsInStock, Comment)
        VALUES('9', '1', '23', '23', 'kut', '20.29', '18.29', '19.10', '23', '19')
```

it shows such error

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Products_Type1". The conflict occurred in database "AcidDB", table "dbo.Type", column 'ID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

[image]

Comment: what's the question? Error msg looks straightforward enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to insert a record into Products with a TypeID that doesn't exist in the table Type.

There is not record in the table Type with the ID "1".

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the FK definition, this is an educated guess:

Your type table does not have an entry with ID of 1.

So, when trying to insert a 1 to the `TypeId` column, a matching entry on the `Type` table can't be found and the constraint fails.

Unrelated: 
Why are you passing a string (`'1'`) to an `INTEGER` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

you are inserting the typeId 1 into your table, but it seems that there is no typeId 1 defined in your type-table.

btw: you don't need to put the int-values into ''!

Answer (score 1):

You don't really ask a question, but I guess you don't understand the error message...
It is very simple: your Products.TypeId field has a FK constraint linking to table Type.ID.
Since there is no type.id of value '1' your insert triggers an error.
Maybe, as pointed by karlis, you have a type 1 (without quotes) !